# How to dynamically change material ui icon depending on the backend response?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a table and in this table, there is a column named status, and in this column, three values are returned from the backend, which are "approve", "Review" and "pending". My problem is that I want when the status is "approve" to change the shape of the icon to "VerifiedUserIcon" (import VerifiedUserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VerifiedUser';) and When the status review that changes the shape of the icon to "VisibilityIcon", just like this picture

[image]

How can I solve my problem?

```
<TableCell className="p-4 md:p-16 truncate" component="th" scope="row">
  <Chip
    style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}
    icon={<FaceIcon />}
    label={n.status}
    variant="outlined"
  />
</TableCell>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const statusIcon = (status) => {
  switch (status) {
    case "verified":
      return <VerifiedIcon />;
    case "review":
      return <ReviewIcon />;
    default:
      return <DefaultIcon />;
  }
};

<TableCell className="p-4 md:p-16 truncate" component="th" scope="row">
  <Chip style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }} icon={statusIcon(n.status)} label={n.status} variant="outlined" />
</TableCell>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ternary operator` to specify icons, assuming only 3 states

```
<TableCell className="p-4 md:p-16 truncate" component="th" scope="row">
  <Chip
    style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}
    icon={
      n.status === "approve" ? (
        <VerifiedIcon />
      ) : n.status === "review" ? (
        <ReviewIcon />
      ) : (
        <PendingIcon />
      )
    }
    label={n.status}
    variant="outlined"
  />
</TableCell>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even try `Object literals` for your icons by mapping status with related icons something like below.

```
const statusIcon = {
  verified: <VerifiedIcon />,
  review: <ReviewIcon />,
  // other icons based on your status
};
```

Then in your code, you can use the `statusIcon` object and get the icon based on the property.

```
<TableCell className="p-4 md:p-16 truncate" component="th" scope="row">
  <Chip
    style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}
    icon={statusIcon[n.status]}
    label={n.status}
    variant="outlined"
  />
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a list of every available icon can be a bit overkill in some cases so I would propose this:

```
import * as Icons from '@material-ui/icons'

<TableCell className="p-4 md:p-16 truncate" component="th" scope="row">
  <Chip
    style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}
    icon={React.createElement(Icons[YOUR_ICON_NAME])}
    label={n.status}
    variant="outlined"
  />
</TableCell>;
```